# Appending to dictionary in text file in Python inside the brackers {}

Tags: python, file, dictionary, append, brackets

I am trying to append a message along with a name to an empty dictionary in a text file.

```
def tweeting():
    f = open('bericht.txt', 'a')
    message = input('Put in message:  ')
    name = input('Put in your name: ')
    if name == '':
        name = 'Anonymous'
    tweet = name + '; ' + message
    f.write(tweet)
    f.close()
tweeting()
```

The result I am getting is this:

```
Tweets = {

}David; Hello everyone
```

The message goes after the brackets {}. Is there a way to put the message inside the brackets {} ?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. Just take care of the quotes in name and message, if you want the text in your file to be as a dictionary. If they are not typed by user, they must be added to t before t is written in the file:

```
def tweeting():
    with open('bericht.txt') as f:
        t=f.read()
    if ':' in t:  #that means that t has other elements already
        t=t[:-1]+','
    else:
        t=t[:-1]
    message = input('Put in message:  ')
    name = input('Put in your name: ')
    if name == '':
        name = 'Anonymous'
    t += name + '; ' + message + '}'
    with open('bericht.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(t)
```

Comment: Yes this solved it. Might I ask, what happens when you say ' t = t[:-1] + ',' ? Why the [:-1] ?

Comment: This is to separate items in your dictionary with comma. However it must check if there is no other element, in that case it shouldn't add the comma. I will add a condition for this in the code

Comment: Added some condition. If ':' is already in text which means that there is already another element, then comma will be added, otherwise it will not

Comment: ps: don't forget to upvote the accepted answer and/or other ones :) Cheers!

Comment: It worked before as there are already elements in the dictionary. But this is even better.

Answer (score 0):

you have not entered any brackets as such. Just add brackets as follows -

```
def tweeting():
    f = open('bericht.txt', 'a')
    message = input('Put in message:  ')
    name = input('Put in your name: ')
    if name == '':
        name = 'Anonymous'
    tweet = '{' + name + '; ' + message + '}'
    f.write(tweet)
    f.close()
tweeting()
```

Add '\n' if you want it in different lines.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't fix my problem yet. I would like the message to go inside the dictionary in the text file, not behind the dictionary.

Comment: Could you share a sample output which you're looking for please ?